# Why does it count downwards then backwards? Don't want to change it, just understand it

Tags: python, recursion

Why does it count downwards then backwards? Don't want to change it, just understand it.

```
def bounce (n):
    if n > 0:
        print(n)
        bounce(n-1)
    print(n)

bounce(4)
```

result:

```
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Try tracing through it by hand, keeping track of the stack as you go.

Comment: You have two calls to `print`, one before the recursive call is made, and one after the recursive call returns. 0 is only printed once because the first `print` is skipped when `n == 0`.

Comment: You're seeing how the call stack works. Look up recursion and call stacks. And it'll help you see in this particular example if you change the first `print(n)` to `print(n, "before recursive call")` and the second `print(n)` to `print(n, "after recursive call")`

Answer (score 2):

It counts downwards because you print the parameter (when positive) then make a recursive call with the same value minus 1. Each of those recursive calls also prints their input and makes a recursive call, until you get to 0. (That call only prints 0.)

It counts back up because of the last print statement that happens as it exits each recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Between the first `print(n)` and the second `print(n)`, all the smaller numbers will be processed by the recursion.  Only when n is zero does the function print a single line and returns without calling itself.

So if we break it down by recursion depth we get:

```
bounce(4)
   |print(4)                     4   1st print(n)
   |bounce(3)
   |   |print(3)                 3   1st print(n)
   |   |bounce(2)
   |   |   |print(2)             2   1st print(n)
   |   |   |bounce(1)
   |   |   |   |print(1)         1   1st print(n)
   |   |   |   |bounce(0)
   |   |   |   |   |print(0)     0   2nd print(n)
   |   |   |   |print(1)         1   2nd print(n)
   |   |   |print(2)             2   2nd print(n)
   |   |print(3)                 3   2nd print(n)
   |print(4)                     4   2nd print(n)
```

As a general rule, what you do before the recursive function calls itself is performed in order and what you do after is performed in reversed order.

Comment: Excellent breakdown.  Thank you for putting the time into this answer.